# Express res.redirect redirect not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app. I am adding a middleware which redirects user to logout **if token is invalid**.

```
export async function validateAuthTokenMiddleware(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
): Promise<NextFunction | void> {
    try {
        const { context } = req;
        await validateToken(context);
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        logoutAndRedirectUser(res);
    }
}
```

Code for `logoutAndRedirectUser`

```
const logoutUser = (res: Response) => {
    res.clearCookie('my_token')
    res.format({
        json: () =>
            res.status(401).json({
                errors: [
                    {
                        message: 'You must login to see this',
                        errorCode: '0001',
                    },
                ],
                extensions: {
                    location: location,
                },
            }),
        html: () => res.redirect(302, location),
        default: () => res.redirect(302, location),
    });
};
```

I am using this middleware in my route like so. All api request from client goes via this route:

```
router.use('/api', validateAuthTokenMiddleware, graphql);
```

However the redirect is not working as expected.

- I am expecting my browser to get redirect to my '/login' route/page after clearing cookie. Instead I see just 401 for my `/api` call and browser remains on same page. res.redirect(302, '/login') is not triggered.
- I have tried refactoring `logoutUser` to just send `res.redirect(302, '/login')` Instead of res.json. Still doesn't work.

Network snapshot as observed on browser:
[image]

Comment: Are you making this request from Javascript within your web page? Also, what is the accept header on the request (that determines which type of content `res.format()` will send)? And, are you aware that an http request made from your Javascript in a web page does not cause the browser web page to change automatically, no matter what the response status is. The response status comes back to your javascript and if you want the web page to change, you have to get that response, see it's a 3xx and then set `window.location` to the redirected location, thus causing the browser to change the page.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah this makes sense. So I can do 2 things now. Either add a condition on client if received 3xx use window.location and redirect to that page.
Or can I add in accept header of request to accept redirect?

Comment: If the client on the other end is some Javascript, then the redirect will send a 302 response with the `Location` header set, but the browser will NOT automatically change the web page.  That 302 response just goes to the client-side Javascript for it to decide what to do with that response.

Answer (score 0):

My browser makes simple requests with

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,...
```

This means that `application/json` is acceptable (because of `*/*;q=0.8`), therefore your json response is chosen, which is not a redirect. Perhaps reordering the choices within `res.format` helps.

You wrote:

> I have tried refactoring logoutUser to just send res.redirect(302, '/login') Instead of res.json. Still doesn't work.

Can you share your refactored code as well, please?

Answer (score 0):

I end up setting a condition on my Client code. If received 401, redirect to login page.